# Python sockets- How do I connect two different devices?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

I know how to connect devices that are in the same network, however, how do I connect two different devices in different networks using sockets. I know that you must open up a port and whatnot, however my question is how do I do this pythonically without manually doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way as you do it now as long as long as you know the IP address and the port the socket is bound to. You will have to configure your router to do so though.

Unfortunately in order to do that you have to make sure the router and the firewall will allow that package to come through. For example you can access your home router and open the port you wish to communicate and forward the data in that port to a specific machine inside your home network. When data comes to that port your router will forward the data to that computer.

If there is a way to control your router options from python then you can do that just using python. I don't know more details on that though.